# One to many with exclusions

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model A, and a model B that has a ForeignKey to A (one to many relationship). I have a list of the ids of "B" items that my user must not see (call this `forbidden_list`, but I want to find any "A" that has any "B" that is not in that list, even if it has B that are in the list. If I do `A.objects.exclude(child__id__in=forbidden_list)`, I get any A has does not have any of the forbidden B as children, but I don't get A that has both wanted and unwanted B.

Comment: `A.objects.filter(child__isnull=False).exclude(child___id__in=forbidden_list)`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid doesn't make the slightest bit of difference.

Comment: Maybe you can use 2 queries: `A.objects.filter(id__in=B.objects.exclude(id__in=forbidden_list).values_list('fk_to_a', flat=True))`. But I think that this query is not quick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

A.objects
 .annotate(total_b=Count(child__id))
 .annotate(excluded_b=Count(child__id__in=forbidden_list))
 .exclude(total_b=excluded_b)
```

Comment: It doesn't like the second annotate with the `child__id__in=forbidden_list` - I get `FieldError: Join on field 'id' not permitted. Did you misspell 'in=forbidden_list' for the lookup type?`

Comment: Oh, that may be because I'm still using django 1.7 - it looks like query expressions was added in 1.8.

Comment: Try `child__in` or use `pk` instead of `id`.

Comment: Same problem. Like I said, I probably need to upgrade to Django 1.8 or better.